# removing bb codes with regex replace

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to remove BBCode tags through Javascript however I am unable to understand how.

Adding all tags into an array eg:

```
var bbcodes = ["[b]", "[/b]"];
```

Then searching through my text and replacing the bbcode with "".

```
for (i=0; i < bbcodes.length; i++) {
    selTextStrip = selTextStrip.replace(bbcodes[i], ""); 
}
```

Having realised this will only replace the first occurrence I tried to add expression:

```
for (i=0; i < bbcodes.length; i++) {
    selTextStrip = selTextStrip.replace(new RegExp(bbcodes[i], 'g'), ""); 
}
```

However this would do the following:

Change `[b]BBCode[/b]` into `[]BBCode[]`

How can I change the RegExp to suite all these tags:

```
"[b]", "[/b]", "[i]", "[/i]", "[u]", "[/u]", "[s]", "[/s]", "[left]", "[/left]", "[center]", "[/center]", "[right]", "[/right]", "[quote]", "[/quote]", "[code]", "[/code]", "[list]", "[/list]", "[img]", "[/img]", "[spoil]", "[/spoil]"
```

Further to this, If I want to remove the following tags from text -> `[color=red]text[/color]` what expression would I need to remove both `[color=red]` and `[/color]`? Noting that 'red' can change to any length and can also be a hex value (`[color=#ff0000]text[/color]`)

I have tried adding [color=(.*?)] into the array however as before only 'color=' is removed not the #hex value nor the '[]'

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you would need to escape the square brackets: `"\[b\]", "\[/b\]", ...`

Comment: I changed my array to: var bbcodes = ["\\[b\\]", "\\[\/b\\]"]; however only the 'b' was removed.

Comment: sorry, double up the escape character for javascript: `"\\[b\\]", "\\[\\/b\\]"`

Comment: Brilliant, that worked. Any idea for the color one?

Comment: @Matt you can use this: https://github.com/thunderer/Shortcode . Just register `NullHandler` or `ContentHandler` as default handler for all shortcodes and they will be either completely erased or just stripped from shortcode tags. You can also use this: https://github.com/coduo/php-humanizer as it has already implemented shortcode removal features using the library above. Let me know if you need any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
text.replace(/\[\/?(?:b|i|u|s|left|center|right|quote|code|list|img|spoil|color).*?\]/g, '')
```

will also provide the `color=foo` stripping.

Or use

```
text.replace(/\[\/?[^\]]*\]/g, '')
```

to strip all kinds of `[foo something]` tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regex `\[\\?\w*\]`

Look at [this](https://regex101.com/r/xI8xA7/1)